# Send image from Objective VC to Swift configured VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift3, viewcontroller

I am working on a project which somewhere needs to send the edited image to another `ViewControler` using segue or storyboard.

Some points to understand first.

- The `ViewController` i am sending image which is configured using `Objective C`.
- And the image is to be pass that `ViewController` which is configured using `Swift` Lang.

**Problem:**

> The Swift Class which is imported in Objective .m file is not visible so it lets me to create its object to make reference of its members.

I tried:

```
// here i am not able to create SwiftVC class object so i can pass image further
SwfitVC *object = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC_Identifire"]; 
object.image = image; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:object animated:YES];
```

> SwftVC Class is not visible after importing to .m file.

Please have look. Thanks.

Comment: check the link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to make your Swift file visible; in your .m file you'll have to write this import statement.

```
#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"
```

Clean and build then you'll be able to use your Swift class.

Comment: @vaibhav mark it as the answer. so that it would be helpful for others.

Comment: Thanks Aaqib, happy eid.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way:

You can save the image to Document Directory in Objective-c class and fetch it into Swift Class.

Might be a help this logic.